# How to save Windows credentials to a data source in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a shared data source for SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 that uses a specific Windows user ID and password to connect to the database.

Using the Report Manager web interface, if I create a shared data source and specify "Credentials stored securely in the report server", I can check the "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" checkbox.  This tells SSRS that the user ID and password I specify are from a Windows user, not a SQL Server user.

I want to create the shared data source using Visual Studio though.  In Visual Studio I have an option to use stored credentials but there is no equivalent of the "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" checkbox.  SSRS always assumes that user and password are for a SQL Server user, not a Windows user, and thus the connection fails.

Does anyone know how to tell Visual Studio that the stored credentials are for a Windows user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using SS05 but this should still work: use the credentials tab and set a specific user name. That field can be used for windows auth too. If you need a domain name, specify it in the usual: domain\user fashion.